# Conditional Dependencies in GNU Make

Tags: makefile, conditional-statements, gnu

I would like to have my target have conditional dependencies. Below is an example that doesn't work

```
everything: foo bar \
ifndef EXTRA
  biz baz
endif
    recipe_to_do_stuff
```

So if I run `make` it will make `everything` with all the dependencies `foo bar biz baz`. But if I ran `make EXTRA=true` it would make `everything` with only `foo bar`.

Is this a possibility? I could have conditionals that run two separate commands but my target has lots of possible dependencies and I don't want to have two places to change if they need updates. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This was my eventual answer to have an inline solution.

```
everything: foo bar $(if $(EXTRA), biz baz)
    recipe_to_do_stuff
```

Comment: Note: `make EXTRA=false` yields same thing as `make EXTRA=true`

Comment: The problem noticed by @Barney can be solved by using a text function like this:
`foo: bar $(if $(findstring $(mode),extra),baz)`
Then if only if mode = extra does make add the baz dependency.

Answer (score 5):

You can define dependencies in multiple lines by repeating the target name at the beginning of the line:

```makefile
# Makefile
baz:
    @echo baz

bar:
    @echo bar

foo: bar
foo: baz

foo:
    @echo foo
```

```console
$ make foo
bar
baz
foo
```

Hence, you can `ifdef` around one or more of these dependency lines:

```makefile
# Makefile
baz:
    @echo baz

bar:
    @echo bar

foo: bar

ifdef DO_BAZ
foo: baz
endif

foo:
    @echo foo
```

And define the variable if you want the extra dependencies:

```console
$ make foo
bar
foo
$ make foo DO_BAZ=1
bar
baz
foo
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
ifndef EXTRA
  REQ=biz baz
endif

everything: foo bar ${REQ}
    recipe_to_do_stuff
```